# How to remove scientific notation on bqplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, voila, bqplot

I am using bqplot to create a live line graph on jupyter-notebook + VOILA

```
from bqplot import pyplot as plt2
import datetime

x_values = []  #array of datetimes
y_values = []  #array of 10+ digit numbers
plt2.show()

def functionThatIsCalledRepeatedly(x_val, y_val):
    x_values.append(x_val)
    y_values.append(y_val)
    plt2.plot(x_values, y_values)
```

[Part of the Resulting Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK9Ft.png)

My question is, how do I remove the scientific notation from the y-axis. It's a simple task but I have tried a lot of things.

I tried using `axes.tick_format` property of the graph but I think that only works if you have axes objects which I cannot have because they require the mandatory **Scale** property which I cannot use because the graph is live and the x and y scales need to be generated/recalibrated while it runs.

I tried changing `y_values.append(y_val)` to `y_values.append("{:.2f}".format(y_val))` but that converts to a string and bqplot doesn't process it as a number so it ends up with negative numbers on top of the 0 sometimes.

I tried converting to a numpy array and then doing `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` which (obviously) didn't work.

Basically tried a lot of things and I think it comes down to some bqplot property that may or may not exist. Have been stuck for a while. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide axes options with the tick format you want to the `plot` method:

```py
plt2.plot(x_values, y_values, axes_options={
    y=dict(tick_format='0.2f')
})
```

You can see examples of this axes_options (using a scatter plot, but that should work the same) in this notebook: https://github.com/bqplot/bqplot/blob/master/examples/Marks/Pyplot/Scatter.ipynb

Comment: thanks this was v helpful